# Add controls to CFileDialog

Tags: c++, winapi, wtl

How can I add a simple checkbox on a CFileDialog?

MFC seems to have a function `CFileDialog::AddCheckButton`, which unfortunately is not implemented in WTL..

These missing features (which I find elementary) are getting annoying. Or is WTL just not for me?

Answer (score 2):

This is not so elementary. `CFileDialog` is not exactly the implementation for this functionality, and instead is a wrapper over `OPENFILENAME` and friends standard API. It is possible to change layout and add controls, however keep in mind this is achieved by hooking/subclassing the window and adding controls and message handlers via Win32 API.

WTL does not offer you helper methods for customization, but it enables the hooking internally (initializing `lpfnHook` and mapping it to WTL-standard `StartDialogProc` dialog proc) to help you with quick start. You are supposed to derive from this class, override message handling and you can start your customization from there.

Also note that this is a wrapper over deprecated API. WTL also provides you with fresher stuff: `CShellFileOpenDialog`, `CShellFileSaveDialog`.

#### Code Snippet

This is how you extend the class:

```
#include <atlmisc.h>

class CMyFileDialog :
    public CFileDialogImpl<CMyFileDialog>
{
public:

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyFileDialog)
    CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CFileDialogImpl<CMyFileDialog>)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
    COMMAND_HANDLER(123, BN_CLICKED, OnTestClicked)
END_MSG_MAP()

private:
    CButton m_Button;

public:
// CMyFileDialog
    CMyFileDialog() :
        CFileDialogImpl<CMyFileDialog>(TRUE)
    {
    }

// Window Message Handler
    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        CRect Position;
        ATLVERIFY(GetWindowRect(Position));
        ATLVERIFY(SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, Position.Width(), Position.Height() + 50, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE));
        CRect ButtonPosition;
        ButtonPosition.left = 10;
        ButtonPosition.top = Position.Height() + 10;
        ButtonPosition.right = 90;
        ButtonPosition.bottom = ButtonPosition.top + 20;
        m_Button.Create(m_hWnd, ButtonPosition, _T("Test"), CControlWinTraits::GetWndStyle(0), CControlWinTraits::GetWndExStyle(0), 123);
        bHandled = FALSE;
        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT OnTestClicked(UINT, INT, HWND, BOOL&)
    {
        AtlMessageBox(m_hWnd, _T("Test"), _T("Debug"), MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Then you do:

```
    CMyFileDialog Dialog;
    Dialog.DoModal(m_hWnd);
```

And you get your control on the bottom:

[image: Screenshot - See Test Button]

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. From which class should I derive exactly? (`CFileDialogImpl`?) I also tried the `CShellFileOpenDialog` but I'm getting 'undeclared identifier' error; atldlgs.h is included (WTL 8.0).
Also, for the message handling overriding, I have no clue how I would do that.. Are you talking about the functions `OnInitDone`, `OnFolderChange`, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the great help. The button is working but it only appears after resizing the dialog, and all controls disappear when I change folder (http://i.stack.imgur.com/CL9ES.png). I'm using WinXP, does that make a difference?

Comment: I have no answer to your last question. My run was on Win 7 and obviously there is a difference (and UI itself is different). As it often happens with UI hooking, the answer is likely to be easy to find but it needs a hands-on debugging: using Spy++ to check current window state, message tracing.

Comment: Maybe you don't respond to some message, or instead you need to post additional fake resize notification after you are finished initializing your addition. Or, you might need to add your controls first, and then resize container window, or you need to additionally post-handle the sizing notification yourself and update your controls.